# lotus notes editor/author levels limitations

Tags: ibm-domino

When we assign editor rights to Lotus Notes clients they can edit and save received emails. How do I restrict them so they are not able to edit and save received emails?
When we give author rights users can't create personal folders, is their any solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a user as Author instead of Editor you can enable additional privileges like Create personal folder/views. They're the check boxes below the Access drop down in the ACL.

Comment: Comment from Farooq: I do this, but users having author right (create personal folders/views option is checked ) fail to create personal folders in lotus notes

Comment: Do you know the difference between private/personal/shared folders? Not the dictionary definition, I mean in terms of visibility in Lotus Notes.